# Is there any Javascript variant of Trac's WikiFormatting?

Tags: javascript, markdown

I am current using the showdown.js for client-side markdowns. I find that the WikiFormatting of Trac is more feature-rich for my kind of app. Does anyone know any JS implementation of the same?

Comment: Trac is opensource, so why don't take the Wiki Formatting feature from there?

Comment: Yes, and looking for a JS version of that, if some has done it. Trac doesn't have JS variant, you need to post to the server to get the formatting done.